# Default action gets 404 for only one page (asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, http-status-code-404

I test my app only on local cassini web server, and I get strange thing.

One Index page works right in default manner, second shows 404, but when use full version Controller/Index - works normal. Only difference I found is that in first sample there is no slash in the end, and in second slash exists, but link that points on corrupted is without slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you show us your routes? Or even better: Try to use Phil Haack's excellent (and essential) Route Debugger. It will tell you which route(s) are hit for a given request, or if no route is hit at all.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

Works only with MVC Beta though, not if you use any older Preview Release of MVC.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for RouteDebug, the Problem was because I called Controller by name of one of the directory in the root, like Models, Views and etc!

Comment: +1 for explaining why in case someone else has a similar problem.

Comment: This was so helpful. I made this mistake myself and couldn't explain it when compared to another developer machine.

Answer (score 4):

if you could post your routings we could help you better, but for now I'd suggest you to debug it using the [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).